# свекровь or тёща

Tags: перевод

The dictionary gives both as mother-in-law. Any difference?
Someone said one is for wife the other for husband but I could not confirm this.
Any clarification welcome.
Thanks

Comment: the name for father-in-law also depends on the party, in case you're interested, **свёкр** - husband's father, **тесть** - wife's father, most spouse's kin names depend on the party, there're also wife's and husband's siblings

Comment: Elena's answer is correct and should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 6):

Тёща - мама жены, only a man can have тёща.

Свекровь - мама мужа, only a woman has свекровь.

https://youtu.be/-aFimeu-4DM?t=116

Comment: Correction: if two men are married to each other, they both have свекровь and if two women are married, they will both have теща.

Comment: We don't have traditional names for such things, and homosexual marriages are not legal in Russia. So, most probably in such cases they will have none. Or as they agree with the parents.

Comment: That doesn't mean that you can't be in a same-sex marriage and speak Russian. Or write a book about alternative reality where such marriage is legal in Russia.
Now technically "теща" is defined not as man's spouse's mother, but as wife's mother, so by definition, there are two "теща" in two-women marriage and two "свекровь" in two-men marriage.

Comment: @Alissa absolutely. And I’ll just add that that the language isn’t any kind of property of the Russian federation. Russian is spoken in numerous countries. And the fact that homosexual marriages aren’t legal in Russia isn’t that interesting from the linguistic point of view.

Comment: @Alissa. Language is like a living organism (used by a number of speakers in different countries), it evolves quite slowly, much slower than the legal or political concepts, so language is not able to quickly keep up with the societal changes. In think it is not possible to MAKE language change, it changes in a more or less natural way as the speakers use some concept in there speech (e.g. it took decades for КОФЕ to evolve in a two gender word, by the same token I think it might take years for such words as *теща* to evolve, or they may start using another word, etc.)

Comment: @alexsms, and we are speaking of the current state of the language.

Comment: Well, traditional terms describe traditional reality. In the reality of rural medieval life of Russia - there was no homosexual marriages, thus the words in the questions do not relate to them. Those terms specifically describe relationships within "extended family" of a village, where many generations lice together in the same place intertwining for decades if not centuries. Outside of those realities those terms loose their relevance. They become something between obsolete and redundant. There are many terms of "extended family" relationships that urban citizens like me don't know.

Comment: Would same-sex marriage become a regular thing in Russia - the distinction between свёкр and тесть would loose any practical meaning and those both words would become just forgotten, so the question about applying their to such a environment is moot.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation by that someone is correct. **Свекровь** is always the *husband's mother*, **тёща** is the *wife's mother*.